# hasRole("ROLE_USER") not working in spring boot3 with springsecurity6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created one LoginFilter in spring boot where i have created the user authentication object and after that redirected to dashboard page

my below files are:

**LoginFilter.java**

```
import jakarta.servlet.*;
/*import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;*/
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class LoginFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,ServletException
    {

           Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
           SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
                        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
                        updatedAuthorities.add(authority);

                        authentication =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("myemail.gamil.com", null, updatedAuthoritie
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            
            this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response,"/dashboard");
       
    }

}
```

**WebSecurityConfigDashboard.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;



@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigDashboard {

    @Autowired
    private LoginFilter loginFilter;

    @Bean
    //authentication
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService1(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("user1")
                .password(encoder.encode("123"))
                .roles("ROLE_USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user2")
                .password(encoder.encode("123"))
                .roles("ROLE_USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/dashboard*").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .failureUrl("/loginError")
                .and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout").and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(12)
                .expiredUrl("/logout");

        http.addFilterAfter(loginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();


    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer1() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/resources/images/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**LoginController.java**

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard")
    public String dashboard(Model model,Principal principal,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        System.out.println("/dashboard called:------------------------>");
        System.out.println("PRINCIPAL:--------------->"+principal.getName());
        return 'dashboard';

    }

   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("/login called:------------------------>");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("/logout called:------------------------>");
        return "logout";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginError", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginError(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "LOGIN FAILED");
        return "login";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String error(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "error";

    }

   
}
```

when I calling /dashboard url in browser the it goes to login page instead of dashboard i have created UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken in filter class.

If i remove **.hasRole("ROLE_USER")** and instead put **.permitAll()** and then if I hit /dashboard then the method with /dashboard is called but principle object getting null

I have using spring boot 3 with spring security 6

I dont't know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

A common oversight is not realizing that `roles()` and `hasRole()` will add the `ROLE_` prefix for you.

So, instead of doing `hasRole('ROLE_USER')`, please do `hasRole('USER')`. And instead of doing `roles('ROLE_USER')` when creating the user, do `roles('USER')`.

I've added [a Spring Security ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12581) to clarify this.

Comment: tried with hasRole('USER') and roles('USER') but not working

Comment: is it necessary to use the classic approach of creating 3rd table Roles with granted authority? or is there a cleaner way to do it now in spring 3?